# (an alternative for) Creating dynamic CSS in a STYLE element per Svelte component

Tags: custom-element, svelte, svelte-component

I am learning Svelte by converting my existing ([proof concept](https://chessmeister.github.io/)) Chess Custom Element/WebComponent.

One objective is to highlight the squares a dragging Chesspiece can move to

[image]

In my Custom Element it is fairly easy with a Stylesheet (inside Board shadowDOM !!! )

```html
<style id="moveFromSquare"></style>
```

Then a mousenter on a square creates the CSS with the correct squarename
(for screenshot: local variables `at='D5'` and `piece='black-knight'`)

```js
let squareMouseEnter = () => {
    [boardcustomelement].root.querySelector('moveFromSquare').innerHTML=
    piece
      ? `div[at=  "{at}"  ]{
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 var(--boxshadow-size) var(--boxshadow-color);
         }
         div[defenders*=  "{at}"  ]{
            font-weight:bold;
            color:green;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 var(--boxshadow-size) var(--boxshadow-color);
        }`
      : ''
}
```

No need for looping over previous squares to clean classnames,
No need for looping over squares again to set classnames

#### But I am learning Svelte...

Everything is a Svelte object: Board, Square, Piece (inside Square)

[image]

There can be multiple Boards on a page,
since there is no shadowDOM, to apply my CSS approach:

- I need to get the `svelte-xxxxx` className for one Board (what is the easier way?)
- then create a (global) `<STYLE>` element for every board using the `svelte-xxxxx` className everywere required

**But I wonder if there is a more (reactive) Svelte way of creating this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got (for now) is creating the dynamic CSS in a (Svelte) DIV (Childnode of the Board)
than transferring it to the Components STYLE element:

```html
<script>
    import {afterUpdate} from 'svelte';
    let DynamicStyleDIV;
    let parentClass;
    let square='D3';//todo handle dynamic update
    let CSS = x => `{${x}}`;

    afterUpdate(()=>{
        parentClass = DynamicStyleDIV.parentNode.className;
        let selector = DynamicStyleDIV.className+'-style';
        setTimeout(() => document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = DynamicStyleDIV.innerHTML);
    })
</script>


<div bind:this={DynamicStyleDIV} hidden>
    .{parentClass} div[at="{square}"][at="{square}"]{CSS('background:gold')}
</div>


<style>
    div{/*required because an empty style element is ignored*/}
</style>
```

#### But this only works in the Svelte REPL

Where styles are `<style>` elements in the document, and not rules in **bundle.css**